# How to sum values Java Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I need some help, i was trying to get the sum of the values but im stuck 
map values i want to sum

```
Grades grades = new Grades(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
Grades grades2 = new Grades(Arrays.asList(2,3,4,5));
Grades grades3 = new Grades(Arrays.asList(4,5,6,1));
Grades grades4 = new Grades(Arrays.asList(1,2,2,4));

HashMap<Pupil, Grades> map = new HashMap<Pupil, Grades>();
map.put(pupil, grades);
map.put(pupil1, grades2);
map.put(pupil2, grades3);
map.put(pupil3, grades4);
```

I tried to do it by using for-each

```
int sum = 0;
for (int a : map.values()) {
    sum += a;
}
```

But im getting an error `"incompatible types: Grades cannot be converted to int, line 49"`

```
class Grades{

    private List<Integer> grades;

    public Grades(List<Integer> grades){
        this.grades = grades;
    }
}
```

Comment: how `Grades` class looks like?

Comment: `map.values()` returns a collection of `Grades`s objects, it is totally different from an `int`.

Comment: And the end goal is unclrear, do you want to get new `Map<Pupil, Integer>` where value is sum of grades belong to particular `Pupil`or just `int` which the sum of all values for all `Pupil`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method [`HashMap.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#values) returns a `Collection<V>` so here a `Collection<Grades>`, so when iterating you got a `Grade`. Then each `Grade` has a list of `int`

```
int sum = 0;
for (Grades g : map.values()) {
    for(int a : g.getGrades()){ // use the getter name you have in Grade class
        sum += a;
    }
}
```

---

Using `Streams` it'll look like

```
 int sum = map.values()                    // Collection<Grades>
              .stream()                    // Stream<Grades>
              .map(Grades::getGrades)      // Stream<List<Integer>>
              .flatMap(List::stream)       // Stream<Integer>
              .mapToInt(Integer::intValue) // IntStream
              .sum();                      // int
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip 1 : For better understanding of what exactly the return type of your method would look like, you can hover pointer of calling method, so you will see something like below in the picture, by that you will get better understanding

[image]

Tip 2 : When you are initializing data members in your constructor, you no need to write setters untill and unless you want the change the value of datamember, but getter are must as you need to get the values which are initialized at the time of object creation.

Hope you are clear with above two points, now coming to the problem statement : PFB code for sum of 'v' in HashMap

```
public class StackOverFlowProblem {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Grades grades1 = new Grades(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
    Grades grades2 = new Grades(Arrays.asList(2,3,4,5));
    Grades grades3 = new Grades(Arrays.asList(4,5,6,1));
    Grades grades4 = new Grades(Arrays.asList(1,2,2,4));

    HashMap<Pupil, Grades> map = new HashMap<Pupil, Grades>();
    map.put(new Pupil(), grades1);
    map.put(new Pupil(), grades2);
    map.put(new Pupil(), grades3);
    map.put(new Pupil(), grades4);

    int sum =0;
    for (Grades gradeValues : map.values()) {
        for (Integer grades : gradeValues.getGrades()) {
             sum += grades;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}

```
class Grades{

private List<Integer> grades;

public Grades(List<Integer> grades){
    this.grades = grades;
}

public List<Integer> getGrades() {
    return grades;
}
```

}